# How to call shell script from net assembly

Tags: .net, linux, unix

Need to call unix shell script from a Net assembley, how would I do it.. and return tabular result(key value pair(s)) to the caller.

Comment: Do you mean when running under Mono on Linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running your code in Mono on Linux, you should be able to do something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "myscript.sh";
proc.Start();
```

I see you have now added that you need to be able to parse the output from the shell script. Take a look at [this](http://www.mono-project.com/OutputFromConsoleApp) more complex example that shows how to get the output of the script.

It is hard to give advice on how to actually parse the output, as you don't give us an example of what the output looks like.

Comment: He'd also have to redirect StandardInput in order to get the tabular result back to the caller.